# Why is the android app showing links to deleted questions in the feed?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, deleted-questions, android-app-feed

On Stack Overflow site, it's okay that deleted questions stick around since high rep users can see the question and see that it is pink.  This visually indicates the question is deleted. However, why does the mobile app  have the link to a question that has been deleted and you click on it and get a spinning circle only to then be alerted that the question cannot be found?

Why even bother showing it?  Can the mobile app (android) please filter out deleted questions from the feed?  I don't see any purpose in showing them.